# Split vertical spacing in two continuity pages

Tags: spacing

I want to construct a macro named `\vs` which typeset a constant vertical spacing, e.g. `\vs{40em}` will get 40em height of white spacing. I know there are many ways -- `\vskip`, `\vspace`, etc... -- to achieve this. But, all these methods fail if encountering pagebreak, as shown in my attached figure produced by the following MWE. Anyone can help me with this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}
some text.\vskip10em
question 1...\vskip40em
question 2...\vskip40em
question 3...\vskip40em
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that the space can be splitted and be in part on one page and in part on the next, you could try a loop with small chunks. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\manyvspace { m }
 {
  \par
  \int_step_inline:nn{#1}{\vspace*{1em}\goodbreak}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\begin{document}
some text.\vskip10em
question 1... \manyvspace{30}
question 2... \manyvspace{40}
question 3... \manyvspace{40}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a better way to use `\manyvspace` like this: `\manyvspace{25.4mm}`, `\manyvspace{2cm}`, `\manyvspace{3em}`... . That is to say, it's just like `\vspace(*)`, but can split white blank(across pages) in two or more pages.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the `*` form:

```
\vspace*{4cm}
```

This answers the question in the title, although looking at your sketch example code, I would have thought you always wanted a question title above the space in which case the space should never fall at the top of the page so dropping space at that point should not be an issue.

Following further comments it seems you don't really want space at all but rather a white paragraph of (say) 5 lines, which may be broken over a page, for which you can do

```
\section*{Some title}
\mbox{}\\
\mbox{}\\
\mbox{}\\
\mbox{}\\
\mbox{}


\section*{Some other title}
\mbox{}\\
\mbox{}\\
\mbox{}\\
\mbox{}\\
\mbox{}
```

Comment: Following your suggest, I replace `\vskip40em` with `\vspace*{40em)` , but get a typeset which is not my desire. I just want the vertical spacing can cross pages, that is to say, the top position of the next page can also white blanked.

Comment: @lyl vspace* will make space at the top of the page if a page break happens befpre it. If you mean that you want 40em of space allows a blank in the middle then that is a different question with a different answer.  `\mbox{}\\\mbox{}\\\mbox{}\\\mbox{}\par` will make 4 lines of "space" that can have a page break in the middle.

Comment: Repeat some times of \mbox\\, well, it's a hacky trick. Thank you!

Comment: @lyl I would not see it as a hack at all, rather the most natural markup for that request. You want something that acts like a 5 line paragraph with no text, so a 5 line paragraph with no text seems to be the natural thing to use.